# Image Dataset for course project

Tags: dataset, databases

I am currently studying a machine learning course and now we are asked (each student) to find an image dataset to work on for the course project. I am new to ML and it has been a week and I am trying to find a good dataset (easy and not complicated) to work on, but all I found are ones for tough topics such as lung cancer detection, plant disease detection,... etc. So please someone help me to locate a good one for a beginner.

Comment: This is a a classy and easy one https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats assuming that others, such as MNIST, have been  covered in your lectures already.

Comment: @Sammy Many thanks for your help. But can I have a dataset a little bit harder than this?

Comment: Well, it's a bit of a guessing game. Google street view house numbers is another relatively easy one. Can you be more specific what you are looking for? For example: type of task, dataset size, etc.

Comment: @Sammy thank you very much for your help . Is this the dataset : http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/ ? Can you further explain the task to achieve ( like what is exactly the output of ML model ) ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Have a look at the paper linked on the website. You'll find a description of a classification task applied to it.

Comment: @Sammy Many thanks!